# How can I check the types of derived classes? (C++ Instanceof)

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Let's say I have some base abstract class and three different classes that derive and implement its methods. Is there is a 'Type' object like as in C#? Or in other words, how do I get instances of all these classes?

```
#ModuleBase.cpp
class ModuleBase {

};

#Module1.cpp
class Module1 : public virtual ModuleBase {

};

#Module2.cpp
class Module2 : public virtual ModuleBase {

};

#Module3.cpp
class Module3 : public virtual ModuleBase {

};
```

Comment: C++ does not have reflection. (yet)

Comment: @MutexMorgan There are no built-in features for that (for both things). Welcome to C++. :P

Comment: how can a base class know its derived class? just think about codebase like google's codebase with millions of classes, compiler have to go through all of the classes to find the derived classes

Comment: You can't do it in C++.  You can find very basic information about a type (`std::type_info`) through RTTI (the thing that enables dynamic_cast<>), but you can't learn its parent-classes (plural because C++ allows multiple inheritance), or the classes that derive from it.   There are, of course, ways of _explicitly_ registering classes as derivatives of a common base-class, but it's something you have to do in your code. Here's one: http://web.archive.org/web/20100618122920/http://meat.net/2006/03/cpp-runtime-class-registration/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `instanceof` like methods that can detect the type of an object using templates and [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) ([**1**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/omJ6XVthQOU68Z4A)) or [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)  only for polymorphic objects ([**2**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hyuXsh4ON42euXHS)).

**1** [Live sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/omJ6XVthQOU68Z4A)

```
template<typename Base, typename T> inline bool instanceof(const T) {
   return is_base_of<Base, T>::value;
}
```

```
int main() {
   Module1 module;
   if(instanceof<Module1>(module)) {
      cout << "Module1" << endl;
   }
   if(instanceof<Module2>(module)) {
      cout << "Module2" << endl;
   }
   if(instanceof<ModuleBase>(module)) {
      cout << "ModuleBase" << endl;
   }
}
```

**2** [Live sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hyuXsh4ON42euXHS)

```
class ModuleBase { public: virtual ~ModuleBase(){} };

template<typename T> inline bool instanceof(const ModuleBase * base) {
   return dynamic_cast<const T*>(base);
}
```

```
int main() {

   Module1* module = new Module1();

   if(instanceof<Module1>(module)) {
      cout << "Module1" << endl;
   }
   if(instanceof<Module2>(module)) {
      cout << "Module2" << endl;
   }
   if(instanceof<ModuleBase>(module)) {
      cout << "ModuleBase" << endl;
   }
}
```

The object is both of type `ModuleBase` and `Module1`. I think with that you can achieve what you need with these.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, you might *generate* some C++ code doing what you want. Consider for example using [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) from your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. `Makefile`) or write a simple [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/),  or [Python](https://python.org/) script doing what you want (or some ad-hoc C++ generator above [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org), inspired by [SWIG](https://swig.org)), and generating some C++ code per your needs. My obsolete [GCC MELT](http://www.starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) did that (dynamically, at runtime) on Linux.

[Qt](https://qt.io/) has a [meta-object](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html) protocol doing exactly this. You might get inspiration from its [`moc`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html) (which is open source) generating C++ code.

Look also into the ongoing (but -in February 2020- embryonic) [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project. We want to use these ideas, and we are starting to implement them. Observe that on Linux `dlopen` could be called thousands of times [in practice](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c), on shared objects produced by compilation of generated and temporary C++ code.