# How can we check two class are inherited from another?

Tags: c++, inheritance

How can we write a function that takes two parameter of two different class that function need to return  true if these two class inherited from another otherwise return false.

Comment: Please add some details, show the function signature that you would like to implement and the classes you want to use

Comment: Take a look here [How can I get object types in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066535/how-do-i-get-type-object-in-c/60066724#60066724)

Comment: This is known at compile time, so the function will always return the same result. Why do you need such a function?

Answer (score 2):

Defined in header `<type_traits>` integral constant `std::is_base_of`  might be of use if you have static classes. If your case is dynamic, e.g. you have to check if pointer points at object of class-type derived polymorphically from another class, you can use `dynamic_cast`

Comment: wanted to implement my own function rather than using existing API