# Casting children classes dynamically

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

I have the following classes:

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual int do_Something();
};

class ChildA : public Base {
public:
    int do_Something();    // ChildA does something
};

class ChildB : public Base {
public:
    int do_Something();    // ChildB does something
};
```

In my main.cpp I want to create an object `ChildA()` or `ChildB()` based on a specific configuration that the user sets.
My attempt, inside a function `main()` is:

```
...
int config = 1; // selected by the user

Base* classe;
std::cout<<typeid(classe).name() << std::endl;     // check class name
if (config==0){
    classe= new ChildA();
}
else if (config==1){
    classe= new ChildB();
    std::cout<<typeid(classe).name() << std::endl;     // check class name
}
...
```

## Problem

I expect the printed names to be different. Instead, the output is:

```
P4Base

P4Base
```

Comment: What is `renderer`? Is this Python or C++ `if config==0:`?

Comment: I am sorry, I corrected it. It was the class `classe`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60066724/6865932) may steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @ThomasSablik thank you, the question should be correct now.

Comment: No, it's not correct. Obviously you didn't try to compile it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik This is clearly part of a much bigger application, and my question only reports two small snippets where I try to cast a child class based on an external configuration. I obviously compiled it and it returns the same name, or I wouldn't be here asking this question.

Comment: Are you saying that this is valid C++ that can be compiled `if config==0{`? You should create a [mcve]. You should compile and check it before you post it here. How can I be sure that this code reproduces your problem if you didn't check it and it's obviously not your actual code?

Comment: Your code is still not correct but it makes no sense to show you all the syntax errors. You will fix them without compiling the code snippet. As long as I can find syntax errors in your code I know that you didn't test it.

Comment: Next it would help if you post the output of `typeid(classe).name()` (after you fixed the syntax of your code). You could see the problem in the output and you would see what's wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is `classe` (`Base *`) is not polymorphic. It's a simple pointer. You can see it in the output. On Linux with GCC it's: `P4Base`, pointer to `Base`

What you want is `typeid(*classe).name()`. The output is `6ChildB`, object of type `ChildB`.

Polymorphism won't change the type of the pointer (neither static type nor dynamic type) but it changes the dynamic type of the object.

The comment `// check class name` is wrong. The line

```
std::cout<<typeid(classe).name() << std::endl;
```

doesn't check the class but the pointer.

Comment: Thank you. My goal is not that the printed name is correct, but that the correct child class is cast. Should I modify the casting inside the if-else statements,?

Comment: @maurock I can't see any cast in your code. The types are correct. You don't have to do anything. `classe->do_Something()` will call `ChildB::do_Something()`.

Comment: I want the pointer to point to the correct class. Right now, I understand that the pointer is always pointing to the parent class `Base`. Instead, I want the pointer `classe` to point to `ChildB` when the parameter `config` is equal to `1`.

Comment: @maurock A pointer doesn't point to a class. It points to an actual object. `typeid` returns the type. The type of `classe` is `Base *` and you can't change it. But it points to an object of type `ChildB` as you can see here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/sIphh2GJNWadBBbf

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My confusion arises because, if I initialize a variable in the header, this is not correctly retrieved. The example below shows the initialization of `int a=1` in Base and `int a=2` in ChildB. Printing this value returns in 1 instead of 2 https://wandbox.org/permlink/7rwi47MrjUjaT40s Maybe this requires another post?

Comment: @maurock Simple answer: polymorphism doesn't work with variables, only with functions. Use a getter: https://wandbox.org/permlink/EVsmFg3AKkEcS8ts

Comment: This clarifies everything, thanks. Last question: is it good practice to define `virtual int getA() {return a;}` in the header? I thought it was necessary to implement it in the .cpp file

Comment: @maurock That's opinion based. The difference is that everything you define inside the class is implicitly inline. Everything defined outside the class is not inline by default. You shouldn't define functions inside the class that shouldn't be declared inline. Small function often are defined inside the class.